# How to get value from select?

Tags: angular

I have select list:

```
   <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
            <option
              *ngFor="let option of tab.content.value()"
              [value]="option"
              >{{ option.name }}</option
            >
          </select>
```

I have tried to get model `option` as selected value:

```
onChange(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
   <select (change)="onChange($event)">
            <option
              *ngFor="let option of tab.content.value"
              [value]="option"
              >{{ option.name }}</option
            >
          </select>


onChange(data: Event) {
    console.log(data.target.value);
}
```

Comment: I need not obly value I need whole object

Comment: I need pass `option` into onChange(option)